# NSMassFormatter can't convert grams to lbs (NSUnitMass) or display value

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmeasurement

I am trying to modernize my API calls and want to utilize `NSMassFormatter`. The problem is simple. I can't get any output (aiming for imperial locale). `NSMeasurement's` description is correct.

How to make `NSMassFormatter` to display "123 lbs" weight automatically if I provide grams?

```
NSNumber *weightInGrams = @(62453.0);

NSMassFormatter *weightFormatter = [NSMassFormatter new];
weightFormatter.forPersonMassUse = YES;
weightFormatter.numberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_UK"];

NSMeasurement *weightMeasurement = [[NSMeasurement alloc] initWithDoubleValue:[weightInGrams doubleValue] unit:[NSUnitMass grams]];

NSString *weightString = [weightFormatter unitStringFromValue:[weightInGrams doubleValue] unit:NSMassFormatterUnitPound];
NSLog(@"%@", weightMeasurement);
NSLog(@"%@", weightString);

2019-03-26 17:23:37.535156+0100 testasa[65239:9291466] <NSMeasurement: 0x60800002d020> value: 62453.000000 unit: g
2019-03-26 17:23:37.535169+0100 testasa[65239:9291466]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *formatter* does not perform any conversions. It merely formats a quantity. A gram is still a gram in any language.

However, NSMassFormatter does provide a convenience method based on kilograms. So for example:

```
let grams = 62453.0
let measurement = Measurement(value: grams, unit: UnitMass.grams)
let kilos = measurement.converted(to: .kilograms)
let formatter = MassFormatter()
formatter.isForPersonMassUse = true
let s = formatter.string(fromKilograms: kilos.value)
print(s) // "137.685 lb” on my machine
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here in future. You will get correct string if you don't change `NSLocale` in code. If you need to change it do it in System Settings. `stringFromKilograms` is the key method which provides metric depended string. Also it is possible to configure `NSNumberFormatter` to print out rounded values by setting `maximumFractionDigits` to 0.

Once you do this you don't need to check for metric system with `[[NSLocale currentLocale] usesMetricSystem]`

```
NSNumber *weightInGrams = @(62403.0);
NSMassFormatter *formatter = [NSMassFormatter new];
formatter.forPersonMassUse = YES;
formatter.unitStyle = NSFormattingUnitStyleShort;
//formatter.numberFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]; -> source of bug
formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;

NSString *weightString = [formatter stringFromKilograms:[weightInGrams doubleValue]/1000];
```

Prints correctly:

```
(lldb) po weightString3
138lb
```